# Inclusion Handling in MVC 2 / MVCContrib

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, cdn, mvccontrib, minify

I'd like to improve my page by combining and minifying javascript and `CSS` files. Since [MVCContrib](http://mvccontrib.org/) already contains a project called `IncludeHandling`, I took a look at that which unfortunately left me with unanswered questions:

There is quite a set of interfaces and objects involved in the process. Now I'm using `Ninject.Mvc`, but it seems that `MvcContrib.IncludeHandling` is using some additional (home-brewed?) DI? Can I work around this? Has anybody used this and can share some experiences?

Secondly, advice that is often heard is to put static content on different domains so the request does not contain cookies and the like, making it much easier for the server to handle the request. But how can I combine this with automatic inclusion handling - isn't that necessarily served in the same application?

EDIT: Figured that there is really just a single resolve call in the whole thing, i really wonder why they use DI for that... Thinking about a fork there...

Comment: How did you solve it? I'm encountering the same issue.

Comment: Figured it out after downloading the source. You are right, this is a bit ridiculous. This should not require a DI framework. How lame.

Comment: I'm not too happy with MvcContrib in general - actually, removing the dependency to it is on my todo list for next week... I'm currently hoping for the `.csjs` type of solution that might come with the razor view engine and mvc3, otherwise will roll my own, I guess.

Comment: Have you looked at the new SquishIt library? It's so much easier to deal with. Here is the link: http://github.com/jetheredge/SquishIt

Comment: Chuck, many thanks for that link! SquishIt is a very clean solution. I still don't know how to handle inline-javascript, but SquishIt solves the problem of static javascript, CSS _and_ LESS in one place. Very neat! Mind posting your comment as an answer?? ^^

Comment: I wrote MvcContrib.IncludeHandling the way I did so that it was pluggable for others to replace bits of it if they felt like it, like for example if they wanted to use different storage (eg CDN) or different compressor/minifier (eg Google's one or MS' one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `MvcContrib.IncludeHandling` uses MvcContrib's `DependencyResolver` to find the necessary components. It's not very well documented (see the sample site for more detail, although in that case uses a custom injector).

For example, `MvcContrib.Castle` has a `WindsorDependencyResolver` for that IoC container that you can mimic to use NInject (there may be something if you Google around).
The initialization is quite verbose, but goes like this (container is the Windsor container, in your case, use NInject):

```
var httpContextProvider = new HttpContextProvider(HttpContext.Current);
var settings = IIncludeHandlingSettings)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("includeHandling");

container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IIncludeReader)).ImplementedBy(typeof(FileSystemIncludeReader)));            

container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IIncludeStorage)).ImplementedBy(typeof(StaticIncludeStorage)));           
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IKeyGenerator)).ImplementedBy(typeof(KeyGenerator)));
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IIncludeHandlingSettings)).Instance(settings));
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IHttpContextProvider)).Instance(httpContextProvider));
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IIncludeCombiner)).ImplementedBy(typeof(IncludeCombiner)));
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IncludeController)).ImplementedBy(typeof(IncludeController)).LifeStyle.Transient);

DependencyResolver.InitializeWith(new WindsorDependencyResolver(Container));
```

This way you can register all the dependencies that are needed. Beware that you need the includeHandler section in your web config.

```
<configSections>
    <section name="includeHandling" type="MvcContrib.IncludeHandling.Configuration.IncludeHandlingSectionHandler, MvcContrib.IncludeHandling"/>
</configSections>
<includeHandling>
</includeHandling>
```

I hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Asp.Net Ajax Minifier. http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxminquickstart.ashx

It ships with a MS Build task that you can setup where on build it will find and minify Css and Js files in your project...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Unity version of the DependencyResolver setup. I did it as a Unity container extension.

```
public class ConfigureMvcContrib : UnityContainerExtension
{
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        var settings = (IIncludeHandlingSettings)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("includeHandling");

        Container
            .RegisterFactory<IHttpContextProvider>(c => new HttpContextProvider(HttpContext.Current))
            .RegisterFactory<IIncludeReader>(c => new FileSystemIncludeReader(c.Resolve<IHttpContextProvider>()))
            .RegisterType<IIncludeStorage, StaticIncludeStorage>()
            .RegisterType<IKeyGenerator, KeyGenerator>()
            .RegisterFactory<IIncludeCombiner, IncludeCombiner>()
            .RegisterInstance<IIncludeHandlingSettings>(settings);

        DependencyResolver.InitializeWith(new UnityDependencyResolver(Container));
    }
}
```

It is worth noting that the IncludeHandling setup is not ideal for a web cluster setup as is because of the way it does caching. I had to roll my own controller action that took a list of files to combine and minify. I can provide more info if anyone is interested.